# Como tornar essa classe utilizável?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos, classes

No código abaixo, gostaria de retornar uma instância da própria classe com os dados preenchidos através de um arquivo texto. As linhas estão armazenadas dessa forma no arquivo:

> Yug Sekwaf,13-04-1570,2-34,3:21,2.34,2.45,3.01,2:01,2:01,3:10,2-22

A função `sanitize()` se trata de uma função para filtrar os dados no arquivo texto, retornando apenas `strings` com pontos, como se fossem `floats`.

```
class Athlete:
    def __init__(self,aName,aDob=None,aTime=[]):
        self.name=aName
        self.dob=aDob
        self.time=aTime
    def openFile(self,fileName):
        try:
            with open(fileName) as f:
                self.data=f.readline()
                self.templ=self.data.strip().split(',')
        except IOError as ioerr:
            print('Erro na Leitura dos Dados'+str(ioerr))
            return(none)
        try:
            self.name=self.templ.pop(0)
            self.dob=self.templ.pop(0)
            self.time=str(sorted(set([sanitize (t) for t in self.templ ])))
        except ValueError as valerr:
            print('Erro na atribuição dos valores'+str(valerr))
            return(none)
        return self.__class__(self,self.name,self.dob,self.time)
```

Gostaria de tornar as variáveis privadas, e saber se é possível tornar o método `openFile()` estático.

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Não se esqueça de fazer o [tour] para entender o funcionamento do site. Também tratamos dúvidas, regras e procedimentos no [meta] :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando você cria uma classe em Python você tem opção de criar 3 tipos de métodos: Métodos de instância, métodos de classe e métodos estáticos. Vamos às diferenças entre eles.

**Métodos de instância** (*instance methods*)

São os mais comuns e trabalham em cima do objeto/instância daquela classe. Você precisa definir o primeiro parâmetro como sendo `self`, porque internamente a referência do objeto será passada nesse primeiro parâmetro. Exemplo:

```
class Teste:
    def __init__(self, aName):
        self.name = aName
    def exibir_nome(self):
        print('Nome: ' + self.name)

t = Teste('João')
# A referência ao objeto t é passada internamente como o primeiro parâmetro da função.
t.exibir_nome()
```

**Métodos de classe** (*class methods*)

Esse tipo de método não recebe o objeto como parâmetro "escondido", mas sim a classe sendo usada. É útil para criar construtores alternativos, porque com esse tipo de método é possível retornar um novo objeto da mesma classe. Para definir um método como método de classe é necessário usar o decorador `@classmethod` ([documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod)) e definir `cls` como primeiro parâmetro da função. Exemplo:

```
class Teste:
    def __init__(self, aName):
        self.name = aName

    @classmethod
    def criar_maria(cls):
        return cls('Maria')

t = Teste('João')
# Criará outro objeto da classe Teste já com o nome "Maria" definido.
m = Teste.criar_maria()
```

**Métodos estáticos** (*static methods*)

Esse tipo de método não recebe nenhum parâmetro "escondido", nem `self` e nem `cls`, é como uma função normal dentro da classe. Para definir um método estático é necessário usar o decorador `@staticmethod` ([documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#staticmethod)). Exemplo:

```
class Teste:
    def __init__(self, aName):
        self.name = aName

    @staticmethod
    def metodo_estatico(x):
        print(x)

t = Teste('João')
Teste.metodo_estatico(123)
```

---

Note que nos exemplos eu chamei os métodos de classe e estático usando o nome da classe:

```
m = Teste.criar_maria()
Teste.metodo_estatico(123)
```

Mas também é aceito pela linguagem chama-los a partir do objeto:

```
m = t.criar_maria()
t.metodo_estatico(123)
```

Entretanto, o método de instância precisa ser chamado através de um objeto, se tentarmos chamar um método de instância usando o nome da classe dará erro. A não ser que passemos manualmente o parâmetro escondido, que é justamente o objeto:

```
Teste.exibir_nome()  # Essa linha daria erro.
Teste.exibir_nome(t) # Essa linha seria aceita.
```

---

Para o que você quer você deveria usar então um **método de classe**, e não um método estático, porque você quer que seu método `openFile()` retorne um novo objeto da classe `Athlete`. E para criar variáveis locais, dentro desse método, basta usar o nome direto da variável, sem o `self.`

Sua classe ficaria assim, então:

```
class Athlete:
    def __init__(self, aName, aDob=None, aTime=[]):
        self.name = aName
        self.dob = aDob
        self.time = aTime

    @classmethod
    def openFile(cls, fileName):
        try:
            with open(fileName) as f:
                data = f.readline()
                templ = data.strip().split(',')
        except IOError as ioerr:
            print('Erro na Leitura dos Dados' + str(ioerr))
            return(None)
        try:
            name = templ.pop(0)
            dob = templ.pop(0)
            time = str(sorted(set([sanitize(t) for t in templ])))
        except ValueError as valerr:
            print('Erro na atribuição dos valores' + str(valerr))
            return(None)
        return cls(name, dob, time)
```

> Fontes:
>
> - [class method vs static method in Python - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/class-method-vs-static-method-python/)
> - [Python's Instance, Class, and Static Methods Demystified – Real Python](https://realpython.com/instance-class-and-static-methods-demystified/)
> - [What is the difference between @staticmethod and @classmethod? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/136097/8133067)
> - [Meaning of @classmethod and @staticmethod for beginner? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12179271/8133067)